# How to configure Syslinux to load the kernel images from a different partition or disk?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, syslinux

I'm running Archlinux using Syslinux as a bootloader. Right now the kernel image and initramfs are in `/boot` and all of the Syslinux stuff (configuration file and modules) are in `/boot/syslinux`.

I'm planning on moving the Syslinux directory to a different partition, but I don't know how to modify the configuration so it loads the kernel from a different partition.

This is the configuration part I have referring to Arch, how could I tell it to look for everything in a different partition?

```
LABEL arch
MENU LABEL Arch Linux
LINUX /boot/vmlinuz-linux
APPEND initrd=/boot/initramfs-linux.img root=/dev/disk/by-label/RootFS rootflags=,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered rootfstype=ext4 ro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [the ArchWiki's pages on Syslinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslinux), I suppose the only way this is possible is to **[chainload](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Comboot/chain.c32) another Syslinux-bootloader**, like (*untested*)

```
LABEL boot_hd2_2
MENU LABEL Boot second primary partition from thirth hard drive
COM32 chain.c32
APPEND hd2 2
```

Where `hd2,2` also carries Syslinux bootcode, in the usual "boot kernel from here"-style.

(This is kind of clumsy, why not just use Grub2?)

Comment: Yep, apparently this one is the only solution for now as Syslinux doesn't seem to access files in other partitions. I wanted to use a single bootloader, right now I'm chainloading Syslinux from Windows' BCD because Windows doesn't like not to be the boot partition (suspension or hibernation doesn't work correctly). I don't change to GRUB2 because I find it to be pretty slow compared to the old Grub or Syslinux.

Comment: Syslinux chainloads anything, not just syslinux.